# Elastic search NEST - filtered group sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to the elastic search, I have done a bit of research but I could not find the right answer which fits to my requirement. The below query return the results of searched term and surrounding suburbs results together with the filter condition and **I want to sort them individually**, term search should always be on the top and surrounding suburbs at the bottom, I have done the aggregation so I know the count of search term results.

```
double firstTermLatForSort = 0;
double firstTermLngForSort = 0;
int requestedPage = request.Page > 0 ? request.Page - 1 : 0;
FilterContainer termFilters = new FilterContainer();
FilterContainer refineFilters = new FilterContainer();
FilterContainer surroundingFilters = new FilterContainer();
var exactMatches = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<ResidentialDetails>(s => s
 .From(requestedPage * request.PageSize)
 .Size(request.PageSize > 0 ? request.PageSize : 20)
  .Filter(f =>
  {

  refineFilters = f.Term(t => t.Status, "current");
   FilterContainer filter = new FilterContainer();
if (request.Terms != null && request.Terms.Any())
                {
                    var i = 1;
                    foreach (var term in request.Terms)
                    {
                        FilterContainer termFilter = new FilterContainer();
                        if (term.TermType == TermType.Suburb)
                        {
                            termFilter = f.Term(x => x.Address.Suburb, term.Term.ToLower());
                            if (i == 1)
                            {
                                firstTermLatForSort = term.Location.Latitude;
                                firstTermLngForSort = term.Location.Longitude;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (term.TermType == TermType.Region)
                        {
                            termFilter = f.Term(x => x.Address.Region, term.Term.ToLower());
                        }
                        else if (term.TermType == TermType.Council)
                        {
                            termFilter = f.Term(x => x.Address.Council, term.Term.ToLower());
                        }
                        else if (term.TermType == TermType.Postcode)
                        {
                            termFilter = f.Term(x => x.Address.Postcode, term.Term.ToLower());
                        }

                        if (term.TermType == TermType.State)
                        {
                            termFilters |= (f.Term(x => x.Address.StateAbbr, term.State.ToLower())
                                        || f.Term(x => x.Address.State, term.State.ToLower()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            termFilters |=
                                (termFilter
                                      && (f.Term(x => x.Address.StateAbbr, term.State.ToLower())
                                      || f.Term(x => x.Address.State, term.State.ToLower())));

                            if (request.SurroundingSuburbs)
                            {
                                surroundingFilters |= (f.GeoDistance(g => g.Address.Location, geoDistanceFilterDescriptor => geoDistanceFilterDescriptor
                                                                                                                               .Location(term.Location.Latitude, term.Location.Longitude)
                                                                                                                               .Distance("5km")
                                                                                                                               .DistanceType(GeoDistance.Arc)));
                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                    filter = filter && (termFilters || surroundingFilters);
                }

                if (request.PropertyType != null && request.PropertyType.Any())
                    refineFilters &= f.Terms(x => x.Category, request.PropertyType.Select(p => p.ToLower()));
                if (request.PriceMin > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Price.Price).GreaterOrEquals(request.PriceMin));
                if (request.PriceMax > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Price.Price).LowerOrEquals(request.PriceMax));
                if (request.LandSizeMin > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Dimensions.LandAreaSqMeters).GreaterOrEquals(request.LandSizeMin));
                if (request.BedsMin > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Features.Bedrooms).GreaterOrEquals(request.BedsMin));
                if (request.BedsMax > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Features.Bedrooms).LowerOrEquals(request.BedsMax));
                if (request.BathsMin > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Features.Bathrooms).GreaterOrEquals(request.BathsMin));
                if (request.CarsMin > 0)
                    refineFilters &= f.Range(r => r.OnField(x => x.Features.TotalCarSpaces).GreaterOrEquals(request.CarsMin));

                if (request.ExcludeUnderOffer)
                {
                    refineFilters &= f.Term(x => x.UnderOffer, false);
                }
                filter = filter && (refineFilters);
                return filter;
            })              
             .Aggregations(ag =>
             {
                return ag.Filter("SearchTermMatchCount", st => st
                        .Filter(
                            f =>
                            {
                                return termFilters && refineFilters;
                            }).Aggregations(sag => 
                            {
                                return sag.Terms("SearchTermMatch", t => t.Field(sf => sf.Address.Suburb).OrderAscending("_term"));
                                } ));



             })
            .SortGeoDistance(sgd =>
            {
                if (request.Sort == Csn.Dto.Homesales.Enums.SortOrder.Distance)
                {
                    return sgd.OnField(x => x.Address.Location)
                                                .Order(Nest.SortOrder.Ascending)
                                                .Unit(GeoUnit.Kilometers)
                                                .Mode(SortMode.Min)
                                                .DistanceType(GeoDistance.Plane)
                                                .PinTo(firstTermLatForSort, firstTermLngForSort);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            })

            .Sort(st => 
            {
                switch (request.Sort)
                {
                    case Csn.Dto.Homesales.Enums.SortOrder.LatestListing:
                        return st.OnField(x => x.DateCreated).Descending();
                    case Csn.Dto.Homesales.Enums.SortOrder.OldestListing:
                        return st.OnField(x => x.DateCreated).Ascending();
                    case Csn.Dto.Homesales.Enums.SortOrder.PriceHighest:
                        return st.OnField(x => x.Price.Price).Descending();
                    case Csn.Dto.Homesales.Enums.SortOrder.PriceLowest:
                        return st.OnField(x => x.Price.Price).Ascending();
                    default:
                        {
                            if (request.Sort != Csn.Dto.Homesales.Enums.SortOrder.Distance)
                            {
                                return st.OnField(x => x.AdPriority).Descending();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            )
            );

        response.Matches = exactMatches.Documents.ToList();
        response.Count = exactMatches.Total;

        var aggregation = (SingleBucket)exactMatches.Aggregations.Where(a=>a.Key == "SearchTermMatchCount").Select(a => a.Value);
        response.SearchTermMatchCount = aggregation.DocCount;
```

With the above query I am getting something like, if search with the term : Kotara (which is a suburb), I get the result for that suburb and also surrounding suburbs with in the range of 5km.
propertyId:1, address.suburb: "charlestown", price:500,000 (1 record which is surrounding suburb) 
propertyId:2, address.suburb: "kotara", price:500,000 (2nd record, searched term) 
PropertyId:14, address.suburb:"Newcastle", price:400,000(3rd record, surrounding), 
propertyId: 4, address.suburb: "kotara", price:200,000 (4th record, searched term)

But I want the result like 
propertyId:2, address.suburb: "kotara", price:500,000 (1st record, searched term)
propertyId: 4, address.suburb: "kotara", price:200,000 (2nd record, searched term)
propertyId:1, address.suburb: "charlestown", price:500,000 (3rd record which is surrounding suburb)
PropertyId:14, address.suburb:"Newcastle", price:400,000(3rd record, surrounding)

All the "searched term" results should be at the top of the sorting then all the other sorting conditions should come

Comment: Can you post what your current results look like and what you actually want them to look like?

Comment: Updated the question description.

Comment: You might want to look at `function_score` which ranks the docs. Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query

Comment: Why don't you add a distance sort if it is a suburb search and no sorting is specified

Comment: With respect to the suburb center

Comment: If I have only one suburb filter, I would have done that. But if I search with multiple suburbs, that will not be a right result.

Comment: function_score solved my problem, thanks Chandra Praneeth.